# How to remove left padding on dock panel?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, wayland

After a long time I have updated to latest Ubuntu (22.04.1 LTS) and found it pretty annoying that the dock panel has a few "dead" pixels between the left side of the screen and the app icon. As a result, I cannot select an application by simply moving the cursor to the extreme left and clicking an icon. I need to exactly position a cursor to target the app icon.

How can I remove this [spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTW4f.png)? I have tried to edit `#dashtodockContainer` setting in gnome-shell.css, but this has not had any effect.

I’m using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and GNOME Shell 42.5

Comment: No such version as latest. At any time at least 2 versions could be called latest. An actual version number is needed.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and

GNOME Shell 42.5

Answer (score 0):

I installed Dash to Dock and it solved the problem in Ubuntu 22.04: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

Also toggle "Auto-hide the Dock" and "Panel mode" in Settings>Appearance after installing to apply your preferred settings.

Comment: It works! Thanks.